# How to enlarge existing file to specific size

Tags: virtual-machine, dd

I have *hdd.img* file, which I user as HDD for my virtual machine, but it's size is too small, how can I enlarge it?

There is one method, something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ds=10GB count=8 >> hdd.img
```

but it takes a lot of time :(

Comment: The command you wrote will completely overwrite the original content. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, fixed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 seek=new_filesize count=0 of=your_file
```

For example this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G seek=1000 count=0 of=test
```

will enlarge file test to 1000G

Comment: Try it on a test file. It works! All space after old file's content will be filled with "virtual" zeros (sparse file).

Comment: Why doesn't it overwrite the original contents?

Comment: @IvanPerez, because it creates a sparse file: dd actually writes nothing to original file, just setting seek position to given point.

Comment: Be careful about using this dd command on a file that's larger than the number your specifying! This is _not_ appending to the file. It is changing the files actual allocated size on disk.